# Model's defaultValue is evaluated only once in ExtJS. Is there a way to evaluate it at record insertion?

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I noticed that if I set a `defaultValue` for a model in ExtJS, this is evaluated only once. The problem is I would have something like this

```
Ext.define("AnalysisModel",{
    extend: "Ext.data.Model",
    fields: [
        {
            name: "date", 
            type: "date", 
            defaultValue: new Date(),
        }
    ],
});
```

Every time I record is inserted in the store that uses this model, I expect that `date` will be the date of the insertion. On the contrary, `new Date()` is evaluated only once and all records have the same value for `date`. So I have to explicitly insert also `date`.

Is there a way to circumvent this? I'm using ExtJS 5.1

Comment: "I expect that date will be the date of the insertion". Why would that be the case? How is the framework supposed to know you meant `new Date()` as opposed to some static date value? Currently there's no way to do it. You could use a convert method.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli: this is how it works in a database. `convert`  does not work.

Comment: Well, if your database is setting it, just skip the default value and leave it null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `defaultValue: new Date()` is being evaluated when the model is defined; it's part of the arguments to the `Ext.define()` call. That's why it's only being evaluated once.

What you need to do is evaluate the defaultValue later - e.g. when the model is evaluated. The easiest way to do that for a model is to use the `convert` method.

```
{ name: "date", type: "date",
  convert: function(value, record) {
    if (value) { return value; }
    return new Date();
  }
}
```

NB: haven't tested this, but it should work.

Comment: I already tried it, but it does not work. Sorry, I should mention it in question

Comment: @MarcoSulla Well, [this answer does work in a basic fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/11p3), so this answer solves your initial question. You can try to understand what happens in the fiddle, and if you require help to get it working in your program, you would want to post more of your code.

Comment: The fiddle works, the answer does not. The problem is `defaultValue` itself. If you remove it, the code works. I accept the answer if you correct it :)

Comment: Sure. The defautlValue is now removed.